# Nativescript app works on simulator but not on real device. Crash report says EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a `Nativescript-Angular` mobile app. It works on simulator well. But once it's published to Apple store, it works on older model like **iphone 7**, but not on **iphone 10/11/12**. The **ios version** are all **14+** so I don't think that's the cause.

I pulled the crash report from my phone, it just has some error messages like these. Could anyone give me some ideas or point me in the right direction of how to research on this?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000280b350
VM Region Info: 0x280b350 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4324461744
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                   10442c000-104430000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...e.app/LBELite

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [508]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019ffbc658 0x19ffb7000 + 22104
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019ffbcf88 0x19ffb7000 + 24456
2   NativeScript                    0x0000000104da4930 0x104d30000 + 477488

...

Thread 1 name:  JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8ef41ac 0x1b8ecc000 + 164268
...

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d6a58764 0x1d6a4e000 + 42852
...

Thread 3 name:  Heap Helper Thread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8ef41ac 0x1b8ecc000 + 164268
...

Thread 4 name:  Heap Helper Thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8ef41ac 0x1b8ecc000 + 164268
...

Thread 5 name:  Heap Helper Thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8ef41ac 0x1b8ecc000 + 164268
...

Thread 6 name:  Heap Helper Thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8ef41ac 0x1b8ecc000 + 164268
...

Thread 7 name:  Heap Helper Thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8ef41ac 0x1b8ecc000 + 164268
...

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000000280b348   x1: 0x0000000280b34b60   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000034
    ...

   esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault
```

Answer (score 0):

The runtime library you are using, `NativeScript` is supplying a much too low valued data pointer to the objective-C runtime.  When this memory location, 0x000000000280b350, is accessed, the Kernel notices there is no Virtual Memory mapped for that address, giving a Data Abort.  Your `esr` register has top bits binary 100100.  The ARM manual says

> Used for MMU faults generated by data accesses, alignment faults other than those caused by Stack Pointer misalignment, and synchronous External aborts, including synchronous parity or ECC errors. Not used for debug-related exceptions.

A common reason for low-valued data addresses is that there has been code that offsets a value from some other base value, and the thing the gets the base value returned nil, or gave you 0.  Your bad value is kind of large for such a problem (normally you'd see a bad value like 0x230 or something).

The reason I think your code is breaking is that the underlying library must have an architecture-specific aspect of code to it.  It is likely that the code supports Intel (assume you are using an Intel based Mac), and older ARM chips but not the newer chips.  iPhone X is using the A11 Bionic chip.

Are there any other apps you have that use this technology stack but work on the latest hardware?  Do you have an iPhone X, does that work locally?  Is there any updated versions of your NativeScript support you can try?

There is a small chance that the foul-up is due to the App Store re-compiling your BitCode before sending it to the customer, and that has introduced a fault.  Is BitCode enabled in your build archive?

Answer (score 0):

What version of the IOS runtime are you using? I was having similar issues until I updated from 6.5.0 to 6.5.4.